# OpenSSL Random bytes in Ruby vs Elixir

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, cryptography, elixir

This problem is most easily understood by reading my attached Gist: https://gist.github.com/KazW/e77e5c7603d7700d86c1

I have a simple encrypt/decrypt function in Ruby that works. Every time the encryption function is run, a new initialization vector is created using `OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(12)`. When I try to do the same steps in Elixir, using `:crypto.strong_rand_bytes(12)`, it generates an IV that can be used for encryption, but causes decryption to fail.

Stranger still, if I use an IV generated in Ruby, and use it to Encrypt in Elixir. When passing the ciphertext to decrypt in Elixir, the decryption function returns the plaintext without error. I've researched the algorithm in use, the IV is supposed to be random bytes, the important factor is the number of bytes in it (12).

My initial thought is that perhaps I'm calling the wrong OpenSSL method to generate the IV. However, I wasn't able to find any information as to what the correct method would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using String functions to read the data, which only works with Unicode, and UTF8 characters are variable-width. You should use pattern matching instead, which uses single-byte width.

https://gist.github.com/asonge/4f035a38a9b31339d8f5